# Informatica: how to get the auto-generated primary key of a table in Informatica mapping?

Tags: sql-server-2008, auto-increment, informatica-powercenter

My question is very similar to the one below, but on a informatica environment:

[Retrieving the index of an inserted row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008359/retrieving-the-index-of-an-inserted-row)

Here is a brief summary of the issue:  I'm trying to figure out how I can insert a row into a table and then find out what the value of the auto_incremented id column was set to so that I can insert additional data into another table. Our target is SQL server 2008. We have a table which has to be populated by informatica ETLs and the application is also using the same table - so, we can't use informatica sequence generator.

In the past when I have used Oracle database, there was a Oracle sequence generator transformation available in Informatica - but for SQL server, I am not sure.

Any solutions please?

Answer (score 1):

If the values to be populated are pure sequence values and have no other meaning you can use two sequence generators simultaneously.  Use an Informatica sequence generator that generates values from -1 to negative infinity.  At the same time the SQLserver auto-increment field will contain values from 1 to infinity.  There would never be a collision.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sequence generator with the 'Reset' flag enabled so that it begins with 1 each session run, then use a Lookup to cache the current max sequence value from the target table. Then you can predict the sequence number that SQL Server will generate when a record is inserted by adding NEXTVAL to the max value.

Comment: But if some other process is writing to the target table at the same time, then the predicted value will be incorrect.

Comment: Sure, but this is the only way to do it in a single mapping, assuming there is a constraint - otherwise your answer to separate into two mappings is the best solution.

Comment: Yep. I don't think it does any harm to separate the logic into more than one mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Populate the first table (the table with auto incremented id) first. After that is done, run another mapping where you do a lookup to that table, get the ID value by some other identifiable key value in the table, and proceed to populate other tables (using the retrieved ID) as you wish.