# mysql retrieving last inserted auto incremented value

Tags: c#, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP/MySQL: Retrieving the last Inserted Ids for multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285231/php-mysql-retrieving-the-last-inserted-ids-for-multiple-rows)

Mysql table columns ( ID, name)    id- auto increment.

I will retrieve the last inserted id by...

```
  DECLARE value VARCHAR(30); 
   insert into table (name) values ('foo');
   select max(id) into value from table;
```

This is how i m retrieving the max of id.

What happens if multiple insert statements triggers at same time.
Whats the best practice to do this.

1) Locking the Mysql table

2) add one more column and set it to '0' or '1'  technique.

3) Any other ways to do this.

Am using MySql and c# .Net
                                                                       Thanks

Comment: what is the purpose why you still execute this? `select max(id) into value from table;`?

Comment: read this for details:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/get-autoincrement-value-after-insert-query-in-mysql/

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1008382/856202) should help:

Comment: @JohnWoo i want the last inserted ID, which is my PK. its in SP.

Comment: Thanks for the post, it will also use LAST_INSERT_ID(). But what happens if more than one insert will hit the db at the same time from different users. If multiple insert will happens at same time it will take the 'last_insert_id' of 'last inserted table....

Comment: @kishorkumar86 check the answer I advised you and the relevant [manual entry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id). As I understand it is a session scoped operation, so you will always get the latest insertion id on the current session.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`LAST_INSERT_ID();`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) :

```
INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES ('foo');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: Yeah , but i have to do many inserts 3 tables  next to next. But i want the 'id' from the first table.

Comment: Call `LAST_INSERT_ID()` after the first insert and save the value in a variable.

Comment: NIce. but if its in server. and many users inserting at the same time. To the same table?

Comment: @kishorkumar86 LAST_INSERT_ID will return the ID used by the most recently executed INSERT statement.